# Why does nasm on windows copy invert my word size value when copying-it?

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, nasm

When I copy like this :

```
    mov word[esi+edi],0x7FFF
```

In the file I write it to it is copyed like FF 7F

Why does it do this, or how can I invert it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NASM didn't do this. The processor did, because x86 is Little Endian (see [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

You could write `mov word[esi+edi],0xFF7F` if you wanted, but I suspect that the code was correct to begin with, only you didn't take the endianness into account.

Answer (score 3):

The byte order of an intel machine is least significant byte first, that's why it is FF and 7F.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

I do not think you want to invert this.